# Error while building OpenSSL for android using ndk

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, boot2docker

I am trying to build openSSL for android using ndk. I am using dockerFile concept. I have set few environment variables as per suggested in http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android. Now I am getting following error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/Android/openssl/apps'
( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto -ldl}"; LDCMD="${LDCMD:-arm-l
inux-androideabi-gcc}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO
_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H --static -Wa,--noexecstack -march=armv7-a -mandroid -I/And
roid/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include -B/Android/andro
id-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_AS
M -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do echo $x; d
one | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/
g'`; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:
=openssl} openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd
.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o
ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o
s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.
o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o eng
ine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o ${LIBDEPS} )
/Android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -ldl
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_globallookup: error: unde
fined reference to 'dlopen'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_globallookup: error: unde
fined reference to 'dlsym'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_globallookup: error: unde
fined reference to 'dlclose'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_bind_func: error: undefin
ed reference to 'dlsym'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_bind_func: error: undefin
ed reference to 'dlerror'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_bind_var: error: undefine
d reference to 'dlsym'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_bind_var: error: undefine
d reference to 'dlerror'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_load: error: undefined re
ference to 'dlopen'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_load: error: undefined re
ference to 'dlclose'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_load: error: undefined re
ference to 'dlerror'
../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o):dso_dlfcn.c:function dlfcn_unload: error: undefined
reference to 'dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Android/openssl/apps'
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Android/openssl/apps'
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
INFO[0135] The command [/bin/sh -c cd openssl && ./config --static no-ssl2 no-ss
l3 no-comp no-hw no-engine  &&  make depend &&  make &&         ls -hs . && cp l
ibssl.a /Android/output] returned a non-zero code: 2
docker@boot2docker:/home/curl_ssl$
```

Do you have suggestions to resolve above error? I am not able to find what is reason behind such error.

Answer (score 0):

Android has openssl already. Perhaps you do not need to compile them. Try answer from this question [Compiling OpenSSL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437172/compiling-openssl-on-android-with-cocos2d-x-and-ndk)

Comment: addinLOCAL_LDLIBS := -lssl -lcrypto inandroid.mk gives error C:/Users/ppanchal/AppData/Local/Android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lssl
C:/Users/ppanchal/AppData/Local/Android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lcrypto

Comment: Oh, windows... Try to copy libssl* and libcrypto* from emulator as described in the link. Copy them to right platform version that you are using (I saw your platform is android-19).

Comment: I already did it. In fact I copied in all platforms but still no luck.I need to build openSSL because I need to use that with curl. But currently I am not able to build openSSL while I am able to build curl without SSL support. I appreciate if someone can help me building openSSL using dockerFile. Other options are also welcome.