# How to use openssl library in cocos2dx?

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Now I have libssl.so and libcrypto.so, but I don't know how to use them in cocos2dx. It always gives me the error like this:

```
jni/../../Classes/Custom_SSL.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'RSA_new'
jni/../../Classes/Custom_SSL.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to 'PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY'
jni/../../Classes/Custom_SSL.cpp:25: error: undefined reference to 'RSA_size'
jni/../../Classes/Custom_SSL.cpp:27: error: undefined reference to 'RSA_public_encrypt'
jni/../../Classes/Custom_SSL.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to 'RSA_free'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you add next options? APP_LDFLAGS := -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: Yes, I did.But it can't seem to find  -lssl and -crypto. Maybe there is someting wrong in Android.mk.

Comment: Try this how to add libraries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437172/compiling-openssl-on-android-with-cocos2d-x-and-ndk/28437978#28437978

Answer (score 2):

Now I know how to solve this problem. The program can't connect to libssl.so and libcrypto.so, so it will give me the error "undefined reference to ...".
 I add the openssl folder to the external folder.

There is the code of Android.mk in openssl folder.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := openssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libssl.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libcrypto.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := openssl_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libssl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencrypto_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libcrypto.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Next, cd ../cocos, I have to change the content of the other Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dx_static

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2d

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
cocos2d.cpp \
2d/CCAction.cpp \
2d/CCActionCamera.cpp \
2d/CCActionCatmullRom.cpp \
2d/CCActionEase.cpp \
2d/CCActionGrid.cpp \
2d/CCActionGrid3D.cpp \
2d/CCActionInstant.cpp \
2d/CCActionInterval.cpp \
2d/CCActionManager.cpp \
2d/CCActionPageTurn3D.cpp \
2d/CCActionProgressTimer.cpp \
2d/CCActionTiledGrid.cpp \
2d/CCActionTween.cpp \
2d/CCAnimation.cpp \
2d/CCAnimationCache.cpp \
2d/CCAtlasNode.cpp \
2d/CCClippingNode.cpp \
2d/CCComponent.cpp \
2d/CCComponentContainer.cpp \
2d/CCDrawNode.cpp \
2d/CCDrawingPrimitives.cpp \
2d/CCFont.cpp \
2d/CCFontAtlas.cpp \
2d/CCFontAtlasCache.cpp \
2d/CCFontCharMap.cpp \
2d/CCFontFNT.cpp \
2d/CCFontFreeType.cpp \
2d/CCGLBufferedNode.cpp \
2d/CCGrabber.cpp \
2d/CCGrid.cpp \
2d/CCLabel.cpp \
2d/CCLabelAtlas.cpp \
2d/CCLabelBMFont.cpp \
2d/CCLabelTTF.cpp \
2d/CCLabelTextFormatter.cpp \
2d/CCLayer.cpp \
2d/CCMenu.cpp \
2d/CCMenuItem.cpp \
2d/CCMotionStreak.cpp \
2d/CCNode.cpp \
2d/CCNodeGrid.cpp \
2d/CCParallaxNode.cpp \
2d/CCParticleBatchNode.cpp \
2d/CCParticleExamples.cpp \
2d/CCParticleSystem.cpp \
2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.cpp \
2d/CCProgressTimer.cpp \
2d/CCRenderTexture.cpp \
2d/CCScene.cpp \
2d/CCSprite.cpp \
2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp \
2d/CCSpriteFrame.cpp \
2d/CCSpriteFrameCache.cpp \
2d/CCTMXLayer.cpp \
2d/CCFastTMXLayer.cpp \
2d/CCTMXObjectGroup.cpp \
2d/CCTMXTiledMap.cpp \
2d/CCFastTMXTiledMap.cpp \
2d/CCTMXXMLParser.cpp \
2d/CCTextFieldTTF.cpp \
2d/CCTileMapAtlas.cpp \
2d/CCTransition.cpp \
2d/CCTransitionPageTurn.cpp \
2d/CCTransitionProgress.cpp \
2d/CCTweenFunction.cpp \
3d/CCAnimate3D.cpp \
3d/CCAnimation3D.cpp \
3d/CCBundle3D.cpp \
3d/CCBundleReader.cpp \
3d/CCMesh.cpp \
3d/CCMeshSkin.cpp \
3d/CCSprite3DMaterial.cpp \
3d/CCObjLoader.cpp \
3d/CCSprite3D.cpp \
platform/CCGLViewProtocol.cpp \
platform/CCFileUtils.cpp \
platform/CCSAXParser.cpp \
platform/CCThread.cpp \
platform/CCImage.cpp \
math/CCAffineTransform.cpp \
math/CCGeometry.cpp \
math/CCVertex.cpp \
math/Mat4.cpp \
math/MathUtil.cpp \
math/Quaternion.cpp \
math/TransformUtils.cpp \
math/Vec2.cpp \
math/Vec3.cpp \
math/Vec4.cpp \
base/CCAutoreleasePool.cpp \
base/CCConfiguration.cpp \
base/CCConsole.cpp \
base/CCData.cpp \
base/CCDataVisitor.cpp \
base/CCDirector.cpp \
base/CCEvent.cpp \
base/CCEventAcceleration.cpp \
base/CCEventCustom.cpp \
base/CCEventDispatcher.cpp \
base/CCEventFocus.cpp \
base/CCEventKeyboard.cpp \
base/CCEventController.cpp \
base/CCEventListener.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerController.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerAcceleration.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerCustom.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerFocus.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerKeyboard.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerMouse.cpp \
base/CCEventListenerTouch.cpp \
base/CCEventMouse.cpp \
base/CCEventTouch.cpp \
base/CCIMEDispatcher.cpp \
base/CCNS.cpp \
base/CCProfiling.cpp \
base/CCRef.cpp \
base/CCScheduler.cpp \
base/CCScriptSupport.cpp \
base/CCTouch.cpp \
base/CCUserDefault.cpp \
base/CCUserDefaultAndroid.cpp \
base/CCValue.cpp \
base/TGAlib.cpp \
base/ZipUtils.cpp \
base/atitc.cpp \
base/base64.cpp \
base/ccCArray.cpp \
base/ccFPSImages.c \
base/ccTypes.cpp \
base/ccUTF8.cpp \
base/ccUtils.cpp \
base/etc1.cpp \
base/s3tc.cpp \
base/CCController.cpp \
base/CCController-android.cpp \
base/ObjectFactory.cpp \
renderer/CCBatchCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCCustomCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCGLProgram.cpp \
renderer/CCGLProgramCache.cpp \
renderer/CCGLProgramState.cpp \
renderer/CCGLProgramStateCache.cpp \
renderer/CCGroupCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCQuadCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCMeshCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCRenderCommand.cpp \
renderer/CCRenderer.cpp \
renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp \
renderer/CCTextureAtlas.cpp \
renderer/CCTextureCache.cpp \
renderer/ccGLStateCache.cpp \
renderer/ccShaders.cpp \
deprecated/CCArray.cpp \
deprecated/CCSet.cpp \
deprecated/CCString.cpp \
deprecated/CCDictionary.cpp \
deprecated/CCDeprecated.cpp \
deprecated/CCNotificationCenter.cpp \
physics/CCPhysicsBody.cpp \
physics/CCPhysicsContact.cpp \
physics/CCPhysicsJoint.cpp \
physics/CCPhysicsShape.cpp \
physics/CCPhysicsWorld.cpp \
physics/chipmunk/CCPhysicsBodyInfo_chipmunk.cpp \
physics/chipmunk/CCPhysicsContactInfo_chipmunk.cpp \
physics/chipmunk/CCPhysicsJointInfo_chipmunk.cpp \
physics/chipmunk/CCPhysicsShapeInfo_chipmunk.cpp \
physics/chipmunk/CCPhysicsWorldInfo_chipmunk.cpp \
../external/ConvertUTF/ConvertUTFWrapper.cpp \
../external/ConvertUTF/ConvertUTF.c \
../external/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp \
../external/unzip/ioapi.cpp \
../external/unzip/unzip.cpp \
../external/edtaa3func/edtaa3func.cpp \
../external/xxhash/xxhash.c


LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/. \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/platform/android \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/tinyxml2 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/unzip \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/xxhash \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/nslog\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/curl \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/openssl \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/. \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/platform/android \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/tinyxml2 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/unzip \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/edtaa3func \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/xxhash \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/ConvertUTF \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/openssl \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/nslog


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2 \
                -llog \
                -lz \
                -landroid 



LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2 \
                       -llog \
                       -lz \
                       -landroid 

#add shared library (if you need)                  
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := opencrypto
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += openssl

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos_freetype2_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dxandroid_static

#add static library
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencrypto_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += openssl_static

# define the macro to compile through support/zip_support/ioapi.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS   :=  -DUSE_FILE32API
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-extern-c-compat
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS   := -DUSE_FILE32API
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-extern-c-compat

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,freetype2/prebuilt/android)
$(call import-module,chipmunk)
$(call import-module,platform/android)
#add
$(call import-module,openssl)
```

Now I can use these libraries in cocos2dx.