# Use android's libssl.so and libcrypto.so in native C code

Tags: android, openssl, java-native-interface

As per this link ["building the OpenSSL library for Android devices"](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) "some versions of the Android Java system loader will load the system's version of the OpenSSL library, even though you built and included a copy with your application."

So, is it possible link to the system's openssl (System level) in native C code instead of compiling and shipping our own version of Openssl (Application level) in the android application? This becomes more important because we will have to ship 4 versions of openssl (armv7, armv7_64, x86 and x86_64).

Comment: Try the solution from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437172/compiling-openssl-on-android

Comment: look: https://sourcedna.com/blog/20150806/predicting-app-crashes-on-android-m.html